# custom css switch does not run javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a custom switch in CSS that I am using in a template for django. I am loading the javascript file properly but when I go to use the switch I don't get the expected result. The expected result is that the background would change colour this does not work using the switch. I added a button into the template to see if the button would work which it did,

javascript file:

```
function darkModen() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

HTML switch this does nothing:

```
<div class="onoffswitch" style="position: fixed;left: 90%;top: 4%;" onclick="darkMode()">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" onclick="darkMode">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

HTML button that does do what is expected.

```
<button onclick="darkMode()">Toggle dark mode</button>
```

CCS if this is causing the problem:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #000000; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color: #FAFAFA; color: #A87DFF;
    darkMode()
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: #FAFAFA; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 18px; margin: 6px;
    background: #2E2E2E;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 56px;
    border: 2px solid #000000; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
    background-color: #27A1CA; 
}
body {
    color: black;
}
.dark-mode {
    background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
    color: white;
}
```

I have been trying to understand how the button works and the switch doesn't. Does this happen because I cant use onclick inside a `div` tag? I am also wondering if django could cause this if there is special way to use javascript in django. I can see that the javascript file as been loaded prpperly into the site as I can get to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/lighting.js and see the script here.

Comment: I copied the javascript code from a test document I had. I have updated the code to the current javascript file that does have the function named darMode()

Comment: There's absolutely nothing specific to django here - all the client gets is an HTTP response with the generated HTML etc - so as long as your js is properly loaded (which is the case if your buitton works), then it's purely a front-end issue.

Comment: @Dextron are you still having issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create an event handler for the `checkbox` and listen for the `change` event to determine whether it is checked or not to make sure that you are properly applying the `dark-mode` class to the `body` tag.

Here's a possible solution:

```js
var body = document.body;
var checkbox = document.querySelector("#onoffswitch");

checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var isChecked = target.checked;

  if (isChecked) {
    body.classList.add("dark-mode");
  } else {
    body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
  }
});
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="onoffswitch">
    <span>Toggle dark mode on or off.</span>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" id="onoffswitch" />
</div>
```

Also, the `onclick` event on the `div` element is probably not what you want, at least in your situation since you're using a `checkbox` to determine whether the `dark-mode` should be applied or not.

However, the `onclick` attribute on the `input` element that you have is missing the parenthesis (`onclick="darkMode()"`), so if you really want to go that route, you could still do it, but I'd recommend just dealing with the `checkbox` itself and checking if it's `checked` or not.

```js
function toggleDarkMode() {  
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="onoffswitch">
    <span>Toggle dark mode on or off.</span>
  </label>
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="onoffswitch" 
    id="onoffswitch" 
    onclick="toggleDarkMode()"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: The second way works but only works per page. Is therre a way I can tick on one page and it will stay "ticked" on the other pages I have linked to the first page

Comment: @Dextron you could use `localStorage` to store this information - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I have tried to use localStorage but it still wont save across pages

Comment: @Dextron I suggest you create a new question since it's a separate issue with the code that you currently have and I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Please check onclick function name your calling `onclick="darkmode()"` but in javascript you write

```
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

please change `myFunction` with darkmode

it will be look like

```
function darkmode() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

Hopefully now it work